# iterating over two vectors iterators faster than boost_foreach

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

For some reason Iterator are performing much faster than  BOOST FOREACH while iterating over two vectors... I am using visual studio 2012 with optimization enabled. Below are the two pieces of code I compared it with... Am I missing something?

```
typedef boost::tuple<int&, int&> int_ref_tuple;
BOOST_FOREACH(int_ref_tuple tup, boost::combine(v1, v2))
tup.get<0>() = tup.get<1>();
```

vs

```
vector<int>::iterator iIter = v1.begin();
vector<int>::const_iterator jIter = v2.begin();
for (;iIter != v1.end();++iIter, ++jIter)
{
         //this is faster
}
```

Comment: Try using iterators over the result of `boost::combine` and see if BOOST_FOREACH is comparable in that case.

Comment: visual studio 2012 supports C++11 ranged-based for statements.

Comment: Does performance matters in your case? Don't optimize it prematurely

Comment: @Edison.. It does matter... This iteration is a overloaded method and it is called a million times and Perfomance analyser shows this as hot paths.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
BOOST_FOREACH(int_ref_tuple &tup, boost::combine(v1, v2))
```